# Batch file to open the cmd prompt and execute

Tags: batch-file

can any one help me in this.

I want to run the cmd prompt through Bat file.

```
@echo off
cd ..
cd ..
dir /b w:\0*.jpg >abc.csv

pause
```

The above code collect all .jpg from w drive and will store in C drive as abc.csv

Comment: I can able to run it manually.. but through .bat I am unable to run

Comment: Nothing in that code even *attempts* to open a command prompt.  What have you tried? What error did you encounter?  When you run it manually, what exactly do you do?

Answer (score 1):

Is it not simply?

```
@echo off
cd ..
cd ..
dir /b w:\0*.jpg >abc.csv

start cmd || ::This line opens a new prompt.

pause
```